# Use SQL PIVOT in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The scenario is:

Table name is = dw.tm_usage_monthly
Columns are; account ID = unique ID by customer
usage_month = is usage month as 201901, 201902 
uom = Mbps or Nodes
usage = usage by month by account_id and uom

The database has data like below;

[image]

Is it possible to do in SQL? I'm using SQL workbench.

[image]

Comment: im using SQL server.

Comment: made the change :)

Comment: Your sample data and desired output don't make much sense. Are you not providing a lot of the sample data? Also, images of data are nearly useless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). What would really help is to provide the ddl (create table statements) and dml (insert statements). And that should be the data needed to create the desired output you post. That way we have the complete picture. Doing the nested header type of thing is not possible, that is a presentation layer thing.

Comment: I would think that a PIVOT or crosstab (aka conditional aggregation) is a good technique here. You may (and probably do) want the dynamic version.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. Apologies for posting confusing question. This is my first time using stack overflow so I was having hard time figuring out how to write code in the comment section.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select account_id,
       sum(case when month = 201901 and oum = 'Nodes' then usage end) as nodes_201901,
       . . .
       sum(case when month = 201901 and oum = 'Mpbs' then usage end) as mpbs_201901,
       . . .
from t
group by account_id;
```